# ASP.NET Core Razor Page - Add the index route to another page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

Long story short:

I have a page call foo.cshtml that I want to also handle the index route.

i.e.
pages/bar/foo.cshtml

i would like navigation to 
/bar to be handled by foo.

I hate index.chstml names as it is a pain in the ass in the IDE when you have 5 index pages loaded to have a clue wtf you are looking at.

Is there an easy way to handle multiple routes or change the default route for a particular folder? Yes, i know i could make an index page that redirects. Would prefer to avoid the clutter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use many routes, they are evaluated from top to bottom. You can use constraints to filter away routes.

```c#
// Routing
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    // pages/bar/foo.cshtml
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Foo",
        template: "{controller}/bar/{action}/{id?}/{id2?}",
        defaults: new { controller = "pages", action = "foo" },
        constraints: new { controller = "pages" }
    );

    // User route
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "User",
        template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}/{id2?}",
        defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "index" },
        constraints: new { controller = "user" }
    );

    // Auth route
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Auth",
        template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}/{id2?}",
        defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "index" },
        constraints: new { controller = "auth" }
    );

    // Default route (Controller as default)
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        template: "{action}/{id?}/{id2?}",
        defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "category" }
    );
});
```